# Cancel Token axios no funciona react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

tengo un problema, estoy usando un token para cancelar la ultima peticion con axios, este es mi codigo
export const filteredCards = (query) => {

```
    export const filteredCards = (query) => {


 let { limit } = query;
    const url = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list4/${limit}`
    console.log(url);
    const controller = new AbortController();
        const signal = controller.signal;
        console.log('from resposne::')
        axios.get(url, {
            signal
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log('from resposne::', response)
            setFetchData(response);
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if(axios.isCancel(error)) {
                console.log('Request canceled', error.message)
                return
            }
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
}
```

el problema es que no me cancela nada, y en mi barra de busqueda me devuelve la peticion actual + la anterior, no se cual es el problema, esto lo tengo en un archivo externo y lo importo a mi componente

Comment: Que versión de axios estás usando? que yo sepa, la propiedad cancelToken está `deprecated`, deberías usar `abortController`. https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation

Comment: ya la cambie tampoco funciona, de hecho me regresa undefined, ahora actualizo mi pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pero el abortController no funciona "solo". Debes indicarle que debe abortar la petición:

```
let controller = null;
export const filteredCards = (query) => {
    if(controller){
        controller.abort(); //Cancelas cualquier request pendiente
    }
    controller = new AbortController();
    let { limit } = query;
    const url = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list4/${limit}`
    console.log(url);

    console.log('from resposne::')
    axios.get(url, {
        signal: controller.signal
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log('from resposne::', response)
        setFetchData(response);
        setIsLoading(false);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        if(axios.isCancel(error)) {
            console.log('Request canceled', error.message)
            return
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
    })
}
```

Comment: asi si funciona, el problema ahora es que cancela cualquier busqueda que haga y me devuelve un arreglo vacio

Comment: Oh, olvidé que el AbortController no se puede reusar una vez abortado. Debes crear un nuevo abortController para cada peticion. Ya actualicé mi respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: gracias, me costo un poco entender pero si pude implementarlo